# Random Cursor Images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random, cursor

I have a div in the middle of a simple webpage. When I hover this div, I want my cursor to change randomly to a customized image. I know how to set my own cursor image with css. But how to use javascript to make this cursor image different each time we refresh the page?

This website shows exactly what I want to achieve. When we hover an image, the cursor becomes a little icon that is different each time we refresh the page.
https://glossier.com/#!/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you care to share some code please.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want a new cursor every time the page loads or do you want a new cursor for the div every time you hover over it?

Comment: I want a new cursor over the div every time the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array of your cursors, a function to randomly select one, you need to select the element and finally you need to change the style of the element using the cursor property. Something like this:

```js
// The array for your cursors
var arrayOfCursors = ['pointer', 'crosshair', 'help', 'wait'];

// Returns a random element from the provided array
function random(arr){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[num];
} 

// Selects the element
var el = document.getElementById('idName');

// Changes the cursor
el.style.cursor = random(arrayOfCursors);
```

```css
#idName {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="idName"></div>
<hr />
<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Reload to see the effect again</a>
```

EDIT:

It was difficult to read the comment I posted in response so here's how you should be able to bring in your own custom cursors:

1) You could either save them in `arrayOfCursors` like this:

```
["url(images/my-cursor.png), auto", "url(images/other-cursor.png), auto"]
```

2) OR If they're all in the same folder, you could do something like:

```
el.style.cursor = "url(images/" + random(arrayOfCursors) + "), auto";
```

and just save the name of the files (with extensions) in `arrayOfCursors`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so fast and so precisely! I tried by myself in javascript but I cannot figure it out: How can I change the default cursor symbols by my own svg images I have in a folder. I guess I will have to put the name of my files in the arrayOfCursors and than indicate the path? But where?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/ ... You could either save them in `arrayOfCursors` like this `["cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto", "cursor: url(images/other-cursor.png), auto"]` or if they're all in the same file you could do something like: `el.style.cursor = "cursor: url(images/" + random(arrayOfCursors) + ".png), auto";` and just save the name of the files in `arrayOfCursors`.