# Random cursor image from folder on hover

Tags: javascript, php, html, random, cursor

In a simple webpage, I am trying to get a random cursor image when hover over my element. The curser image needs to change between 4 png files (below for simplicity's sake I used system cursors, this isn't the issue). I'd like the cursor to change every time the user hovers of the element, without having to reload the page.
**I'm having trouble creating the random change function**. I guess it needs to be javascript or php. I'm not very competent in either and was unsuccessful in googling solutions. Ideas anyone?
*I've tried* using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114731/random-cursor-images-with-javascript) as a basis, although here you need to reload to change the cursor, and I'd like the cursor to change without reloading. I've put the javascript in the head under script and it doesn't work -- but works in jsfiddle!! No idea why. I'm not sure how far this is from what I need because of the reloading issue.
*Also tried* using [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/) php snippet as a basis but did not work at all. Again no idea why.
This is my code without the change in the cursor... super basic I guess

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
  <script>
  </script>

</head>

<body>


<div style="background: #ee1; width:300px; height:300px;cursor: help;">
  /* I'd like the cursor to change randomally every time the mouse returns to hover over the element. */
  /* change between ['help', 'wait', 'crosshair'] */
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done via JavaScript:

```js
// The array for your cursors
var arrayOfCursors = ['help', 'wait', 'crosshair'];

// Selects the element
var el = document.getElementById('target');

//mouseover event
el.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
    // Changes the cursor to a random from cursors array
    el.style.cursor = arrayOfCursors[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfCursors.length)];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<head>
  <script>
  </script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="target" style="background: #ee1; width:300px; height:300px;">
  /* The cursor changes randomally every time the mouse returns to hover over the element. */
  /* changes between ['help', 'wait', 'crosshair'] */
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. This works in jsfiddle, but not when I put it all in my index.html with the js in <head> <script> - it ignores the js. Any idea why? _my webpage is very simple so unless issues I'd rather keep it a single html._

Comment: Ok I resolved this - I placed the <script> at the end of <body>. The js is more tidy than the 1st answer, what language is the 1st? Can u see other benefits to the js except for tidiness?

Comment: js is the only way this can be done, since it is done on front-end. PHP and other back-end languages won't allow you to dynamically change stuff on front-end.

Comment: the other solution, whichever language it was in, worked just as well although I gather it isn't js. The only difference is I placed it in the html's head, and there was a little more code to it.

Comment: You mean this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022990/11796799 It doesn't do what your originally requested though. And yes, it is in js too.

Comment: It worked and did what I needed, after I slightly modified the code (in my 1st comment to the answer). Thought they were different mostly because of your use or **var** whereas the other guy used **let** to what seemed to me the same thing... Also, your code couldn't getElementById when placed **before** the element in the html, and the other did. Should say I don't know much about js and writing functions really, will read further into that! Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```js
function random(){
//images to be used
let images = ['https://data.whicdn.com/images/309487318/original.jpg?t=1521902468',
'https://data.whicdn.com/images/346786844/original.jpg','https://data.whicdn.com/images/346397546/original.jpg']

//getting component from DOM
let imgComponent = document.getElementById('myImg')
//getting random number from 0 to the length of the array
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()* images.length)
//assigning random image to DOM
imgComponent.src = images[randomNumber]


}
```

```html
<img

style="height : 70px;" id="myImg">

<button onclick="random()"> random</button>
```

Steps :

1. Make array of images to use
2. Generate random number that goes from
   zero to the length of the array minus one (will be used as index in
   array)
3. Reassign the src attribute in image

Comment: thanks! I've changed it slightly as I wanted to cursor itself to change onmouseover. **script**: function random() {     let cursors = ['help', 'wait', 'crosshair']     let imgComponent = document.getElementById('myEl')     let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * cursors.length)     imgComponent.style.cursor = cursors[randomNumber]   } **html**: <button style="height:150px; width:150px" id="myEl" onmouseover="random()"> random   </button> –

Comment: just curious, which language is it? Sorry for the novice question.

Comment: that is still pure javascript